# Increasing computational efficiency of Game of Life recreation

Tags: javascript, performance, computation-theory, conways-game-of-life

I recreated the Game Of Life in JavaScript. It works, but is computationally ineffective. I have this function for waiting between generations.

```
var speed = 500; //milliseconds

function live() { 
    middleMan = setInterval(processGeneration, speed);
    if (!dead) {
         window.clearInterval(middleMan);
         live();
    }
}
```

Nothing happens for 500 ms, then there's a tsunami of computation tasks. This gives ironic combo of dead time and lag. How can I take use of the 500 ms?

Comment: use `setTimeout` to call `live()` and don't call it inside itslef!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function live() { 
    processGeneration();
    if (!dead) {
         setTimeout(live, speed);
    }
}
live();
```

or

```
function live() { 
    processGeneration();
    if (dead) {
         clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
var timer = setInterval(live, speed);
```

or

```
function live() {
    processGeneration();
    if (!dead) {
         requestAnimationFrame(live);
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(live);
```

But be aware that if you use `setInterval`, each call to `live` must take less than `speed`.